# User access to CPT (Custom Post Type) without access to regular posts

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type that for the sake of this question we can call "my_cpt".

I have also created a new role which we can call "my_role".

What I want to do is give "my_role" access to "my_cpt" without adding the "edit_posts" capability because that gives access to other post types which I do not want the role to have access to.

I have tried variations of numerous bits of code I have found but none have worked so I don't really know where to begin. Based on that I don't have any base code to display here.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin like this one should enable you to do this: https://www.role-editor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being easier than I thought.
I created a couple capabilities... "read_my_cpt" and "edit_my_cpt".
The "my_role" has permissions to both the capabilities.
I then just had to change the capability_type for the CPT to "my_cpt" instead of "post"

Comment: At least post the code.. SO isn't really a discussion site.

Comment: @AshleyBrown - I changed the "capability_type" through the CPT UI plugin. Although it could be done via direct code.